# How to have a different buffer list for each tabs in Vim?

Tags: vim, tabs, minibuffer

Is it possible to kind of "attach" a list of buffers to particular tabs within Vim? I am currently using [MiniBufferExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159), which shows all buffers in nice tabs. It can be combined using standard vim tabs but the plugin's buffer list contains all the buffers and using tabs become a bit useless. Here's an example of what I'd like:

Tab A contains a buffer list of:

- FileA
- FileB
- FileC

Tab B contains a buffer list of:

- FileD
- FileE
- FileF

Currently what I have is this:

Tab A contains a buffer list of

- FileA
- FileB
- FileC
- FileD
- FileE
- FileF

Tab B contains a buffer list of:

- FileA
- FileB
- FileC
- FileD
- FileE
- FileF

When speaking about "buffer list" I mean the tab listing the minibuffer plugin gives.

Any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: I'm also looking for a similar setup. NERDTree + MiniBufferExplorer + tabs would be a nice way to have multiple projects in one physical window. The code in the answer below looks to be a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cant think of any Tab based buffer explorers out there but vimscript has got plenty of functions to track of buffers (:he function-list) . I just knocked this up for the hell of it. It might get you to what you want . It just keeps track of tabs in a  vim dictionary. You will need to flesh out the :TabExplorer function or patch the filtered list (ie. g:TabExplorer[tabpagenr()]) into the minibuf plugin

Save it as ~/.vim/plugin/tabexplorer.vim  and source it at startup.

```
let g:TabExplorer = {}

func! StoreBufTab()
    if !has_key(g:TabExplorer, tabpagenr())
        let  g:TabExplorer[tabpagenr()] = []
    endif

    if index(g:TabExplorer[tabpagenr()], bufname("%")) == -1 && bufname("%") != ""
        call add (g:TabExplorer[tabpagenr()],bufname("%"))
    endif
endfunc

func! DisplayTabExplorer()
    4split
    enew
    call append(".",g:TabExplorer[tabpagenr()])
endfunc

au BufEnter * call StoreBufTab()

command! TabExplorer call DisplayTabExplorer()
```

Comment: @michael Thanks a lot for that jump start. I started using that code until I decided to shift to netbeans and its jvi vim plugin as decribed in another question I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276031/how-to-increase-productivity-with-vim-and-eclipse-for-php5-3-projects-possibly-u .